# Mapping in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, conformal-geometry

I have the following two circles in the complex plane, $z = x + iy$, which bound a region, $R$. The equations for the circles and a sketch of the region is given as follows:
$$ x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1\\
x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4 $$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7iVd.png

What I now want to do is map the region bounded by these two circles and sketch some new region, $W$, defined as follows:
$$ W = \{ w = e^{4 \pi/z} \hspace{0.3mm} : \hspace{0.5mm} z \in R \}$$

And I am a bit lost in all honesty. Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by finding out what $S = f(R)$ is for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. Then multiplying by $4\pi$ is easy, and you should know the exponential function well enough to find out what $W = \exp(4\pi S)$ is.

Comment: As far as I'm aware $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} = \cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)$, but being an amateur here, I'm unsure how to apply $e^{i \theta }  = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ again, or how it is that I apply it to those regions? Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Wait, would it be $e^{4 \pi \cos(\theta)}\left[cos(4 \pi \sin(\theta))-i \sin(4 \pi \sin(\theta))\right]$ ?

Comment: Have you already dealt with Möbius transformations?

Comment: No I have not. I am answering questions I have not as of yet been taught how to answer.

Comment: Pity, that would have made it easier to know what the two circles are mapped to under $z \mapsto 1/z$. But we can also do it without that. Write equation of the circle, $x^2 + (y-a)^2 = r^2$, in complex form, $\lvert z - ia\rvert^2 = r^2$, and multiply out $\lvert z - ia\rvert^2 = (z - ia)\cdot \overline{(z - ia)}$. You get the equation $$z\overline{z} + iaz -ia\overline{z} + a^2 = r^2.$$ Write $z = 1/w$ and manipulate the equation until you recognise what curve $w$ describes. That's the image of the circle under $z\mapsto 1/z$.

Comment: That gives you two curves, each the image of one of the circles bounding $R$. Then $f(R)$ is the region bounded by those two curves. It is a region of a simple shape.

Comment: I am sorry, but principally being a physicist I can confirm myself quite lost. (I appreciate you clearly know what you're doing so I thank you very much for your assistance). I understand everything up to the substitution $ z= \frac{1}{w}$ but then I'm gone. I don't quite understand where it comes from either. I should have stuck in the applied world! This is incredibly frustrating.